# Database design for numeric attributes with different convertible units

Tags: database-design

I need to store numeric attributes that can be saved in different units with possibility of conversion. The number of attributes is rather fixed, so there is no need to create dynamic solution. I don't know which option would be the best. So far I have something like that:

```
unit_type(
id,
name
)
```

```
unit(
id,
name,
symbol,
conversion_factor,
type_id
)
```

My first idea was to create pair of columns per attributes. One with value and the second with unit.

```
data(
id,
some_columns,
attr_a_val,
attr_a_unit_id,
...
attr_n_val,
attr_n_unit_id
)
```

My second idea was to create separate wrapper table that holds the value and associated unit

```
attribute(
id,
value,
unit_id
)
```

and then store the references.

```
data(
id,
some_columns,
attr_a_id,
...
attr_n_id
)
```

Can you help me which design is better, or maybe tell other solutions? There probably won't be many data. I expect there would be around 10-15 attributes with different units and maybe up to 100 000 data records.

Comment: Why do you need to store different units of measure in a single column?  That is unusual.  The more common pattern is to have a fixed unit of measure for each column.  Eg `duration` always stored in milliseconds, or the self-documenting `duration_ms` .

The only time this is normally done is with currency conversion, where transactions actually occur in multiple currencies.

Comment: I wanted to give user possibility to choose the unit. For example if he type value of power, he could choose HP or kW, so one user could type the value in HP and the other in kW.